# Why complexity of removing last element from List is O(1) and O(n) for the arrays?

Tags: c#, algorithm

The question may sound pretty primitive, but it has spawned as the result of a (lively) discussion about the (best case) complexity of removing an element from a List (at the end).

Here are some points I have considered before posting this question:

- Complexity of removing an element at the end of a `List<>` is O(1)
- Complexity of removing any element (be it even the last one) from a static array is O(n), as it requires a new array.

Now keeping in view the above two arguments and the fact that we have an array in the background of `List<>` implementation as well.

So why does the `List<>` operation lead to O(1) and the same for the array into O(n) when both are involving the recreation of an array? Or am I missing something here? Thanks!

UPDATE: Just to clarify, this question's major focus is not on why the last element removal's complexity is O(1), but rather on why it's O(n) for array vs. O(1) for `List<>`. The title has been updated to reflect the changes. Thanks to the answer (which addresses it) and other comments..`

Comment: When you remove an item from a `List<T>` by index, you need to copy all of the items which appear after it one space forward in the list, in order to close the gap you just left. If you remove the last element, that's no cost; if you remove the first element, you'll have to copy every remaining element. In general, then, the cost of removing an arbitrary element from a list scales with the number of elements in the list, making it `O(n)`. This [matches the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: @canton7 Right. And how does it differ in the case of an array?

Comment: @FailedScientist See my full answer

Comment: @OlivierRogier As I have already mentioned that its O(1) in my question. But how does it differ in the case of an array?

Comment: @FailedScientist There is no "remove" from an array. You can copy the remaining n-1 elements into an array of size n-1, which requires O(n) time, or you can set the element at your index to `null` (or some other terminal value), an O(1) operation. If you do what `List<>` does with its backing array, and shuffle the remaining elements forwards, you end up with space at the end of the array, and an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: The duplicate explains in a single sentence that, that is detailled by @canton7: removing the last item does not do the array copy https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,3d46113cc199059a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the basis for your question is incorrect: removing an item from a `List<T>` by index is `O(n)`, not `O(1)`. Let me explain...

When you remove an item from a `List<T>` by index (i.e. using `List<T>.RemoveAt`), you need to copy all of the items which appear after it one space forward in the list, in order to close the gap you just left. You can see that quite clearly in [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,917):

```
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException();
    }
    _size--;
    if (index < _size)
    {
        Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index);
    }
    if (RuntimeHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferences<T>())
    {
        _items[_size] = default!;
    }
    _version++;
}
```

If you remove the last element, that's no cost; if you remove the first element, you'll have to copy every remaining element.

In general, then, the cost of removing an arbitrary element from a list scales with the number of elements in the list, making it linear. Indeed, to quote [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> This method is an O(n) operation, where `n` is (`Count` - `index`).

---

With that out of the way, there is a small difference in cost between removing an element from a list, and removing an element from an array.

`List<T>` is backed by an array: the underlying array can be larger than the value returned by `List<T>.Count`. As more items are added to the list the backing array gradually fills up, before a new backing array is allocated and all of the old elements copied over.

This means that you're allowed to have a backing array which is larger than the number of elements in the `List<T>`. If we remove an element from the `List<T>`, we don't need to allocate an entirely new backing array.

An array, however, always has to be exactly sized. If you have an array containing 3 elements, the array has to have a `Length` of exactly 3. If you want to reduce that to a `Length` of 2, you need to allocate a whole new array with that length.

Any change in size to the array therefore means you need to allocate a new array of the correct size, and copy over everything you care about.

Comment: Thank you. So even if I remove the last element of a`List<>` by index, it will be O(n) operation?

Comment: It depends on how you define `n`. As I explained, the specific case of the last element is O(1), and the general cost of removing an element by index is O(n) *where n is `Count - Index`*.

Comment: @FailedScientist The _algorithm_ is `O(n)`, executing that algorithm on a `List<>` of size `n` for the nth element does not require `n` operations.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Yeah, the 3rd last para cleared the confusion in List's implementation by array vs. intrinsic array itself

Answer (score -2):

It is common in implementing list-like data structures, to allocate the underlying memory as arrays but sized to contain many list elements, keeping track of the position of the last-used array entry.  When more space is needed during insertion of new entries, allocation is generally increased by about 50% (control of starting size and growth policy is an implementation detail).

Therefore removing an entry from the tail of a list generally involves no more than decrementing the variable used to track the position of the last element - an O(1) operation since no (de)allocation or moving of other list elements is required.

*However* note that [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is used to classify algorithms according to their limiting (worst-case) behaviour/requirements.  The underlying memory allocated to lists must still be managed and although growing and shrinking arrays and moving entries around should be performed less frequently than for pure arrays, they are O(N) operations.  While your question makes a statement that is probably generally true, it assumes specific implementation details which need not be (particularly that deletion never gives rise to shrinking of the underlying array).